# Convert PDF to MD using pdf2md

Tags: node.js, fonts, markdown, pdf.js, pdf-conversion

I am encountering an issue with the Turkish language in the output file while utilizing **pdf2md** library. This problem seems to manifest inconsistently across various documents, appearing in some instances but not in others.

[pdf2md github](https://github.com/opengovsg/pdf2md)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM4bC.png)

The message when i converting example-normal.pdf file :

`Warning: fetchStandardFontData: failed to fetch file "FoxitSans.pfb" with "UnknownErrorException: Unable to load font data at: C:\Users\lorens\Desktop\pdf-md2\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\standard_fontsFoxitSans.pfb". Writing to example-normal.md... Done.`

The message when i converting the example-withe-error.pdf file :
`Warning: fetchStandardFontData: failed to fetch file "FoxitSerifBold.pfb" with "UnknownErrorException: Unable to load font data at: C:\Users\lorens\Desktop\pdf-md2\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\standard_fontsFoxitSerifBold.pfb". Warning: fetchStandardFontData: failed to fetch file "FoxitSerifBoldItalic.pfb" with "UnknownErrorException: Unable to load font data at: C:\Users\lorens\Desktop\pdf-md2\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\standard_fontsFoxitSerifBoldItalic.pfb". Warning: fetchStandardFontData: failed to fetch file "FoxitSerif.pfb" with "UnknownErrorException: Unable to load font data at: C:\Users\lorens\Desktop\pdf-md2\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\standard_fontsFoxitSerif.pfb". Warning: fetchStandardFontData: failed to fetch file "FoxitSansBoldItalic.pfb" with "UnknownErrorException: Unable to load font data at: C:\Users\lorens\Desktop\pdf-md2\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\standard_fontsFoxitSansBoldItalic.pfb". Warning: fetchStandardFontData: failed to fetch file "FoxitSerifItalic.pfb" with "UnknownErrorException: Unable to load font data at: C:\Users\lorens\Desktop\pdf-md2\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\standard_fontsFoxitSerifItalic.pfb". Warning: fetchStandardFontData: failed to fetch file "FoxitSans.pfb" with "UnknownErrorException: Unable to load font data at: C:\Users\lorens\Desktop\pdf-md2\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\standard_fontsFoxitSans.pfb". Writing to example-withe-error.md... Done.`

you can refer to the files illustrating the normal scenario:

[Normal Scenario PDF File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W-vjGT7aaXKhxKFosM5VKyDbP7WQgkIQ/view?usp=sharing)

[Normal Scenario Markdown File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nCAKvp9TmQDtHTzzP6HbohOOwCKmojZp/view?usp=sharing)

Furthermore, you can view the files showcasing the error scenario:

[Error Scenario PDF File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Q_L5nvekT7zdhvH-VIiuhUGVaW6li8Z/view?usp=sharing)

[Error Scenario PDF-MD File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F__x7DVGZTxIXXwNHKo59XOGiWZ_v9Bz/view?usp=sharing)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oUq7.png)

Answer (score 0):

> "UnknownErrorException: Unable to load font data at: C:\Users\lorens\Desktop\pdf-md2\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\standard_fontsFoxitSans.pfb". Writing to example-withe-error.md... Done.

The font path missing a **"\"**, the path should be some `C:\Users\lorens\Desktop\pdf-md2\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\standard_fonts\FoxitSans.pfb` instead of `C:\Users\lorens\Desktop\pdf-md2\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\standard_fontsFoxitSans.pfb`.

Check whether you can config some options to change the font path.